# Swift Youtube API Inline mode doesn't work

Tags: swift, swift3, webview, youtube, youtube-api

Im having a problem playing a video from youtube api, even though I set the allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true it still doesn't seem to work, I even tried to initialize the player with the inline param but it didn't work neither...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.playerView.delegate = self
    playerView.webView?.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    playerView.webView?.allowsLinkPreview = true
    //playerView.isHidden = true
    //playerView.load(withVideoId: "60ItHLz5WEA")
    playerView.load(withVideoId: "60ItHLz5WEA", playerVars: ["playsInline":1])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it, I had a misspell ;c
    override func viewDidLoad() {

```
self.playerView.delegate = self
playerView.webView?.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
playerView.webView?.allowsLinkPreview = true
//playerView.isHidden = true
//playerView.load(withVideoId: "60ItHLz5WEA")
playerView.load(withVideoId: "60ItHLz5WEA", playerVars: ["playsInline":1])}
```

in playerVars the property should be "playsinline" and not "playsInline" silly me.... it works fine now thx for everyone helped